# How to put multiple regular expressions into gsub?

Tags: r

I want to erase the character which are not one of: letter, number or blank space.

I tried with `[:punct:]` but it erases polish letters.

Given `textToClean <- "polish letters: ł Ł; ż Ż ź Ź ą Ą ę Ę ó Ó ń Ń ć Ć 43434 ; ; ;!"`

I want the output as:
`polish letters ł Ł ż Ż ź Ź ą Ą ę Ę ó Ó ń Ń ć Ć 43434`

I tried this:

```
textToClean <- "polish letters: ł Ł; ż Ż ą Ą ę Ę ó Ó 43434 ; ; ;!"
gsub("(\\D)(\\S)(\\W)", "", textToClean) # doesn't work properly!
```

and this:

```
textToClean <- "polish letters: ł Ł; ż Ż ą Ą ę Ę ó Ó 43434 ; ; ;!"
gsub("\\D+\\S+\\W", "", textToClean) # doesn't work properly!
```

but it's bad.

Comment: Try `"(\\D+|\\S+|\\W)"`.  You can use the `|' in a regular expression to denote matching this _or_ that.

Comment: Doesn't work. It returns empty String now.

Comment: To use `[:punct:]` it needs to be in a character class, i.e. `gsub("[[:punct:]]","",textToClean)`

Comment: Yes, but then it cuts polish letters! and I need'em.

Comment: I'm not able to make a string with the Polish letters (copy and paste makes them English).  Something like this is what should work, but we need to know how to identify polish characters in the ASCII space, and that I don't know how to do.  `gsub("[^[:alpha:]|^ |^[:digit:]]", "", textToClean)`.  Alternatively, you can list out the punctuation you want to cut. `gsub("[()!;:,@#$.%^&*]", "", textToClean)`

Comment: this works well `gsub("[()!;:,@#$.%^&*]"`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\p{L}` will match *any* letter and `\s` will match any space, tab or newline. If we negate this with the `^`, we can replace all non-matches with `""`:

```
gsub("[^\\p{L}\\s]+", "", textToClean, perl = TRUE)
"polish letters ł Ł ż Ż ą Ą ę Ę ó Ó    "
```

Note that the numbers are also removed. If you want to keep the numbers, you can use `\p{P}`, which matches *only* interpunction:

```
gsub("\\p{P}", "", textToClean, perl = TRUE)
"polish letters ł Ł ż Ż ą Ą ę Ę ó Ó 43434   "
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the default RE engine sees the Polish characters as punctuation, but the Perl one doesn't.

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", textToClean)
[1] "polish letters     ź Ź   ę Ę ó Ó ń Ń ć Ć 43434   "

gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", textToClean, perl=TRUE)
[1] "polish letters ł Ł ż Ż ź Ź ą Ą ę Ę ó Ó ń Ń ć Ć 43434   "
```

I'd classify it as a bug in the default engine.